# Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter while decode JSON Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct

I try to parse JSON with mvc pattern.I'm trying for the first time. But I'm getting "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter error " I mutated functions and put self where necessary.I can access and use required protocols in ViewController. Everything seems normal What's the problem here ?

```
import Foundation

protocol ItunesManagerDelegate {
    
    func didUpdateSearchin(_ ItunesManager:ItunesManager, product: [ItunesModel])
    func didFailWithError(error:Error)
}

struct ItunesManager {
    
    
    let baseURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term="
    
    var delegate : ItunesManagerDelegate?
    
    var itunesDataArray = [ItunesModel]()
    
   
    mutating func getSearchResult(for terms:String){
        let urlString = "\(baseURL)\(terms)"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }
                if let searchResult = self.parseJSON(data!){
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateSearchin(ItunesManager(), product: searchResult)
                    
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    mutating func parseJSON(_ itunesData:Data) -> [ItunesModel]? {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ItunesData].self, from: itunesData)
           
            
            
                decodedData.forEach { (ItunesData) in
                    ItunesData.results.forEach { (SearchResults) in
                        let  type = SearchResults.wrapperType
                         let  name = SearchResults.collectionName
                         let  url = SearchResults.artworkUrl100
                         let  price = SearchResults.collectionPrice
                         let  date = SearchResults.releaseDate
                         
                         let  itunesProductInfo = ItunesModel(collectionName: name, collectionPrice: price, artWorkUrl100: url, wrapperType: type, releaseDate: date)
                     
                         itunesDataArray.append(itunesProductInfo)
                    }
        
            }
                        
            return itunesDataArray
        }catch{
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need ItunesManager as Struct? Looks like class is what you need. Also I suggest you to make delegate as weak and define protocol ItunesManagerDelegate: AnyObject { ... }

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did as you said and it works. I could not be sure if I got the data properly. I cheked https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=batman this url. It returns 50 result and my array count is 50 but some data are missing.